# How to display my own reward video in my app without using admob

Tags: video, admob, ads

I wanna display a rewarded video in my app but not from admob or any other network ... I have my own 30 sec video for a reward video and i want want the user too click a button and watch my video not admob video and when he finish it he get the points like admob reward video

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new Activity for Rewarded video
2. Add VideoView in XML
3. Set URL for streaming video

   String vidAddress = "url_here";
   Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
4. Set url and start video

   vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
   vidView.start();
5. Set listener when video finish

   videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   //give reward
               }
           });

If user press back button it will not give reward to user. You can add more validation  to confirm the reward.

Comment: Is there a real ex ? Or a video